# return value of a function in super constructor

Tags: java

I have to return a value of a function as argument of super()
in particular I have a class Polygon(Point[] vertex) and a class Rectangle extends Polygon

the class Rectangle takes two parameters in its constructor, they are two Point representing two random vertex of the Rectangle, helpful to calculate the other two

the point is, when I create constructor Rectangle(p1,p2), I have to call super() passing it the vertex array built starting from p1 and p2; 
so why I shouldn't call a function to calculate the array and pass it to super() ?

Comment: The super constructor must be called first, so you can't call a function before it. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864675/why-do-not-call-overridable-methods-in-constructors

Comment: You need to create a method `private static Point[] createVertices(Point p1, Point p2){...}` in `Rectangle`. Then you can call `super(createVertices(Point p1, Point p2))` as the first line in your `Rectangle` constructor.

Comment: thank you!!!!! it works!

Answer (score 1):

The call to the super constructor must be the first call in the method. The easiest solution here it to use a static helper:

```
public class Rectangle extends Polygon {
    public Rectangle (int parameter) {
         super(myhelper(parameter));
    }
    private static Point[] myhelper(int parameter) {
        //Do work here!
        return points;
    }
}
```

If you find your class is little more than complex constructors, it might be a sign that you don't really need a subclass. You can often implement stuff like this:

```
public static Polygon rectangleBuilder(int param) {
   //Do work here!
   return new Polygon(points);
}
```